# Loading multiple modules or controllers in Angular is not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope, angular-ui-router

I am needing to "import" or "use" a Modal Service and my current code that works looks like this

```
angular
    .module("deviceManagement")
    .controller("DeviceDetailCtrl",
    ["$scope",
        "$http",
        "$stateParams",
        "deviceService",
        DeviceDetailCtrl]);
```

So I know that there is a file angularModalService.js  in which it contains

```
var module = angular.module('angularModalService', []);
module.factory('ModalService', ...................
```

With those things in mind I want to "inject" this "ModalService" into my current code,  but it says "undefined" etc..

Above my current code I was trying both of these ways of setting another module, but i'm not sure if i should be setting a module or a controller or both

```
  var app2 = angular.module('app2', ['angularModalService']);
```

Or ..

```
angular
    .module("app2", ['angularModalService'])
    // .controller ???
```

Comment: Please make a demo out of this. Otherwise I don't think nobody can help you with this problem with the information you've provided.

Comment: You only need to specify the dependent modules by using any of the above methods. i.e. `angular.module('app2', ['angularModalService'])`. Then to use the service inject the service in controller i.e. `.controller("DeviceDetailCtrl",'ModalService'....`

Comment: ReferenceError: ModalService is not defined

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Jeremy, there are some things to noted.

1. If you want to use another module as the dependency of your module. You need to inject it into your module. In your case, your code will be.

`angular.module('app2', ['angularModalService']);`

Note that it is equivalent to

```
var application2 = angular.module('app2', ['angularModalService']);
```

The different is you can config your module in the future by two ways.

```
angular.module('app2').config(...)
application2.config(...)
```

2. And if you want to use the factory ModalService in your app2, just inject it into your controller.

`angular.module('app2').controller('SomeController', ['ModalService', function(ModalService) {
  //TODO
}]);`

Seem you still confusing about angular module. Please read this [article](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/module). Quoted

```
var myModule = angular.module('myModule', []);

// add some directives and services
myModule.service('myService', ...);
myModule.directive('myDirective', ...);

// overwrites both myService and myDirective by creating a new module
var myModule = angular.module('myModule', []);

// throws an error because myOtherModule has yet to be defined
var myModule = angular.module('myOtherModule');
```

Comment: How do i use app2 along with my module called deviceManagement ?

Comment: Just call it via angular.module('app2', ['deviceManagement']). It will be the first line of code written to define a module